# Custom WhirlyGlobe Skin

Tags: ios, dictionary, 3d

I have recently been setting up the WhirlyGlobe map kit via the mousebird.github tutorial, and have come across an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I want to display a custom skin for the Globe in place of the plain colors that the default setting provides. For example, I would like to have a dark grey themed map displayed around the globe instead of the light blues, pinks, and yellows that the HelloEarth tutorial default gives.

FYI: I have chosen the Binary Documentation tutorial if that has any weight to a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asked and answered on the WhirlyGlobe github site.